# Gwibber not working at all?

Tags: unity, 12.10, gwibber

Brand new fresh install of ubuntu 12.10, with all updates installed. I've added my facebook account in Ubuntu online accounts. It works fine in Empathy, but neither Gwibber nor the Gwibber Ssocial Lens show anything.

If I open Gwibber, it's just blank. If I manually click refresh it just sits there "refreshing" forever. I've tried removing `.config/gwibber` and `.cache/gwibber` and trying again but same problems occur. What gives here? Is there anyway to make it work?

Comment: Does Gwibber work with Twitter?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).